# Simple Django template question

Tags: python, django

I have a template variable:

```
   {{article.pub_date}}
```

that outputs this:

```
   May 25, 2011, 7:52 p.m.
```

How can I get just the date without the time:

```
May 25, 2011
```

without the:

```
, 7:52 p.m.
```

I only have access to the template tags/variables not the python code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{{ article.pub_date|date:"DATE_FORMAT" }}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Answer (score 1):

```
{{article.pub_date|date:"F j, Y"}}
```

Django uses the same [formatting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) as PHP date objects.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can set a default format if you want a format used all over the site

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#date-format